# To print the answer from the series -> x^3 - x^5 + x^7 - x^9 +

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
    {
        int x,n;
        float sum=0;
        printf("Length and Value");
        scanf("%d%d",&n,&x);

        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            sum+=(pow(x,2*i+1) * pow(-1,i+1));
        }
        printf("%f",sum);
        return 0;
    }
```

I'm trying to solve this series in C language. Am I doing something wrong in the above code?

Comment: Please avoid using words like _"somethin'"_, _"doin'"_ etc. This is not a chatroom.

Comment: okay, thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome, FYR, you may want to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why do need to ask if you are doing something wrong? What sample input and output are you using/expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're a bit wrong. In your code

```
 printf("%f",sum);
```

`sum` is an `int` and using `%f` to print the value of an `int` is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The function [`pow`()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow) returns a `double`. You may want to change your `sum` to type `double`.

If you don't mind using your own version, a better looking implementation, without using `pow()` will be

1. Store the existing value.
2. Multiply by `x * x` on each iteration
3. Take care of -ve sign for even numbered iteration.

Comment: how 'bout now? I just changed it.

Comment: Well if you don't mind, can you tell me by writing the code? It would be easy to understand then.

Comment: That would be cheating. This answer gives you everything you need.

Comment: @AshishMasih Sorry, I can't. This goes against the community rules here. You try yourself, if you face any issues, we'll be happy to help.

Comment: Just to elaborate what Mr. @Bathsheba said,  we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Coding is getting harder for me by each question.

Comment: @AshishMasih No issues, don't worry. You try, we'll be helping you onhce you're stuck. Best of luck!!. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, your `printf` has the wrong format specifier for an `int`: use `%d` instead. But for non-integral `x`, you'll want to refactor to a `double` anyway, so `%f` will probably be retained.

Secondly, don't use `pow`: it will not be precise (probably implemented as `exp(log)`) and you don't need to evaluate the power from scratch for each term.

Keep a running power: i.e. compute `x * x * x` initially, then successively multiply that by `x * x` for subsequent terms. Don't forget to alternate the signs: you can do that by multiplying by -1.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to find x^3,x^5 that is power in odd. so do a little change in your for loop. write this instead of your code. and if you give a large x or n value then it is preferable to declare sum as a long data type

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
    {
        int x,n;
        long sum=0;
        printf("Length and Value");
        scanf("%d%d",&n,&x);

        for(int i=2;i<=n;i+=2)
        {
            sum+=(pow(x,i+1) * pow(-1,i));
        }
        printf("%l",sum);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `pow(-1,i)` is awful.

Comment: it can do in different ways

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are trying to evaluate a series that diverges for all points outside and on the circle of radius one (as a complex series).  If you use an `int` for x, you will get each time values bigger and bigger, oscillating around 0.  Try it with numbers of `||x|| < 1`  (this means `double` or `float` for x)

All the other answers posted are also usefull to get sooner to the expected value.